# Why do eyes close when we sneeze?

Tags: eyes, reflexes

It is a behaviour that is very difficult to control. We can't sneeze with eyes open. Is it a reflex of brain to protect the eye from possible injury in sneezing motion or the neural pathway for sneezing is programmed to do so?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20131129-why-our-eyes-close-when-we-sneeze).

Comment: So there is no explanation?

Comment: There are lots of things, most of which are indeed quite common like this one, about which we don't know yet. But there are proposed reasons and mechanisms for them. I am busy right now, so somebody will definitely give you a nice answer for this.